# pdo_mysqli extension is not installed

Tags: magento2

Readiness check says all modules are installed

[image: Readiness check says all modules are fine]

But on  Database step it gives error that `pdo_mysqli` extension is missing.

[image]

**Magento Version:** Magento-CE-2.1.2

**PHP Version:** PHP 5.6.27-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli)

**OS Version:**  Ubuntu 14.04

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.33
**Output of:** `php -m | grep mysql`

- mysql
  -mysqli
- mysqlnd
- pdo_mysql

Comment: check PHP extension intl installed or not on your system.

Comment: @SHPatel intl is there.

Comment: do search for mysqli enable pdo_mysqli from your php.ini file just remove the semicolon (;)

Answer (score 1):

It can be a mysql version issue

I had it when my server was MySQL 5.5 and M2 needs MySQL 5.6 or 5.7

I don't use Ubuntu but I suspect it came with 5.5 not 5.6

---- updating mysql on ubuntu ---

If you already have live apps, backup the database and check the changes between 5.5 and 5.6

according to other posts (I'm not an ubuntu expert please be careful!)

```
sudo apt-get remove mysql-server;
sudo apt-get autoremove;
sudo apt-get install mysql-client-5.6 mysql-client-core-5.6;
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.6;
```

updating the mysql-php modules

```
sudo dpkg -P php5-mysql
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

Comment: I tried upgrading to mysql 5.6 and restarted apache, but still getting same error.

Comment: Double check that everything is the right version database and also update php module php5-mysql. 

It seems updating might mean "uninstall old fully, install new". (edited answer above - but please I don't use Ubuntu so validate this with your knowledge). 

If it is all the correct version and you restarted mysql, apache etc. then I am stumped.

Comment: I did the same way, mysql version is `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.33, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper` , but no luck.